# Java newSingleThreadExecutor garbage collection

Tags: java, multithreading, executor

Consider the following Java code

```
void doSomething(Runnable r1, Runnable r2){
  Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  executor.execute(r1);
  executor.execute(r2);
}
```

when I invoke the doSomething method, the executor is created and performs the tasks r1 and r2 sequentially one after the other.

My question is: what happens once the two tasks r1 and r2 terminate?

I suppose the executor object will be garbage collected, but I do not know whether it will be also shutdown. If the executor creates a new thread for its execution, will this thread result in a resource leak?

Comment: You could use ExecutorService and then call shutdown once you've submitted your tasks for execution. The ES will wait until the tasks complete before terminating.

Comment: You can also use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with zero core threads so that threads are reclaimed when there are no tasks to be run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I suppose the executor object will be garbage collected, but I do not
>   know whether it will be also shutdown.

Actually `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` under the wood creates a `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` instance which will call `shutdown` on `finalize` indicating that it will be shut down automatically when being garbage collected.

However, I don't believe that it is a good idea to rely on it too much as it is more an implementation detail that may change from one version to another, you should rather shut it down explicitly instead to prevent any unexpected bugs.

Comment: Do you have any references to the fact that a FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService instance is created?

Comment: yes here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29

Comment: @ichfarbstift The code. But that aspect of the code is not guaranteed "by contract," so don't depend on it. Call `shutdown()` before your `ExecutorService` reference is lost. And note that even though `shutdown()` has been called, the `ExecutorService` will run until previously submitted tasks are completed.

Comment: @Nicolas That means that if I want to be sure that the thread is destroyed in the code above executor should be an instance of ExecutorService, and I should call executor.shutdown() after the execute(r2)?

Comment: I have seen this recently and don't  know what the scenario it is that the ExecutorService would be actually finalized. Since the live threads have reference to the ES it appears it will never actually be finalized. The only way it would happen is if there are no live threads actively, then I guess it would be finalized.

Comment: @ichfarbstift yes that's it

Comment: In addition to the wrapper class with the finalizer being an implementation detail, its finalizer is also intended only as a safety net. There's no guarantee that it will be executed promptly. An explicit call to `shutdown()` should be preferred over relying on the finalizer maybe getting called some maybe distant time in the future.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)  we can read

> "An unused ExecutorService should be shut down to allow reclamation of
>   its resources."

Basically, you will have to terminate the executor service manually. While the executor object in itself will be garbage collected, it's internal threads will not.

Comment: The threads created have a reference to the `ExecutorService` they run in. As long as they are alive, the `ExecutorService` will not be eligible for GC.

Comment: @erickson The documentation does not promise that anything in particular will happen if your code looses reference to the `ExecutorService`, and it does warn you that you should shut it down if you want the "resources" to be reclaimed.  If you want your code to "run anywhere", then you probably should believe what the javadoc says, and not assume anything about what the javadoc leaves unsaid.

Comment: Long ago, before `Executor`, I wrote a pretty fancy thread pool that could detect if it had been improperly discarded and shut its workers down; the workers referenced the pool that "owned" them via a weak reference.

Answer (score 0):

Objects can only be GC'd if that object is not referenced by a GC root. What is a GC root? The most common ones are System classes and a running thread. An ExecutorService will create and maintain running threads, so even though the ES is created within a method, the ES will still be reachable and not GC'd.

As others mention, you will need to shutdown the ES for it to be GC'd.